# Обнулить эвент после выполнения

Tags: jquery

Мне надо чтобы после того как функция по нажатию на кнопку отработала, без перезагрузки страницы, воспользоваться ей еще раз в других дивах с контентом.

```js
<script>
$('#loadmore').click(function(){
    $('#mores').css("display", "inherit");
    $(this).css("display", "none")
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Не совсем ясна суть проблемы. Что мешает воспользоваться ?

Comment: У меня есть много контейнеров с разным контентом, они привязаны к списку селект. Когда я что то выбираю в селекте, показывается соответсвующий контейнер с содержимым, 18 фото, в каждом контейнере есть кнопка View More, по нажатию на которую появляется укрытый контейнер с дополнительными фото в данном контейнере.Мой код на эту кнопку работает, но только один раз в одном контейнере. Если же я после того как на неё нажал в контейнере 1,выбираю в селект контейнер 4 и он загружается, то кнопка view more уже не работает. Как сделать чтобы кнопка могла во всех контейнерах работать а не один раз?

Comment: Незнаю как в jquery, но чистый js при выборке по ИД выберет только 1-ый элемент

Comment: Но дело думаю не в этом, jquery скорее всего выберет все элементы. Как вариант, вешать евенты после прогрузки соответствующего контейнера. Если устроит, могу накидать вариант на чистом js (недолюбливаю jquery)

Comment: Накидайте, пожалуйста! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не используйте на Вашей странице повторяющиеся `id`. Этот атрибут должен однозначно идентифицировать элемент - отсюда и название. Замените их на `class="loadmore"` и `class="mores"`.

```
$('.loadmore').click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".row").find('.mores').css("display", "inherit");
    $(this).css("display", "none")
});
```

---

P.S. Логично было бы дать ссылку на Ваш предыдущий вопрос, чтобы дать отвечающим контекст, в котором выполняется код, приведенный в вопросе.

Comment: Отличный вариант! Спасибо.
Вот так работает как надо:
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mores').hide();
  $('.more').click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".row").find('.mores').slideToggle('slow');
});
});
</script>

Comment: @Vadim Пожалуйста. Рад был помочь.

Comment: "P.S. Логично было бы дать ссылку на Ваш предыдущий вопрос, чтобы дать отвечающим контекст, в котором выполняется код, приведенный в вопросе."
Проект пока что на локалке, даже не знаю его будущего домена :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
function loadContainer() {
    var select = document.querySelector('[name=js-containers]');
    var selectedOption = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    var containers = document.querySelectorAll('.js-container');
    containers.forEach(function(el){
        el.style.display = 'none';
    });

    var currentContainer = document.querySelector(selectedOption);
    currentContainer.style.display = 'block';
    currentContainer.querySelector('.js-hidden').style.display = 'none';
    currentContainer.querySelector('.js-view-more').style.display = 'block';
    currentContainer.querySelector('.js-view-more').addEventListener('click', function(evt){
        evt.target.style.display = 'none';
        currentContainer.querySelector('.js-hidden').style.display = 'block';
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    loadContainer();
    document.querySelector('[name=js-containers]').addEventListener('change', loadContainer);
});
```

```css
.js-container {
    display: none;
}
.js-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <select name="js-containers">
        <option value="#js-container1">Container 1</option>
        <option value="#js-container2">Container 2</option>
        <option value="#js-container3">Container 3</option>
        <option value="#js-container4">Container 4</option>
        <option value="#js-container5">Container 5</option>
    </select>

    <div class="js-container" id="js-container1">
        <div class="js-visible">Visible part of container 1</div>
        <div class="js-hidden">Hidden part of container 1</div>
        <button class="js-view-more">View more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="js-container" id="js-container2">
        <div class="js-visible">Visible part of container 2</div>
        <div class="js-hidden">Hidden part of container 2</div>
        <button class="js-view-more">View more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="js-container" id="js-container3">
        <div class="js-visible">Visible part of container 3</div>
        <div class="js-hidden">Hidden part of container 3</div>
        <button class="js-view-more">View more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="js-container" id="js-container4">
        <div class="js-visible">Visible part of container 4</div>
        <div class="js-hidden">Hidden part of container 4</div>
        <button class="js-view-more">View more</button>
    </div>
    <div class="js-container" id="js-container5">
        <div class="js-visible">Visible part of container 5</div>
        <div class="js-hidden">Hidden part of container 5</div>
        <button class="js-view-more">View more</button>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но у меня работает не совсем так как мне нужно и ошибка в браузере почему-то.
Можно попросить помочь вставить функцию:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mores').hide();
$('#loadmore').click(function() {
    /*$('#mores').css("display", "inherit");
    /*$(this).css("display", "none");*/
    $('#mores').slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
  });
}); 
внутрь:
$('#selectportf').on('change', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(".cont").addClass("hidden");
  $("#" + value).removeClass("hidden");
});

Comment: Если тут работает, а в коде нет - значит не внёс в разметку нужные классы и ИД. js-container, js-visible, js-hidden, js-view-more, name="js-containers"

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял:
Ваш код скрывает первый блок и показывать второй.
Вы хотите ещё и действие наоборот (скрывать второй, показывать первый).

Если это так, то Вам нужно только реализовать действие наоборот.
Вы можете это сделать сами, либо воспользоваться моим вариантом.

```js
$('.aa, .bb').on('click',function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('aa')){
  // Если .aa
    $(this).hide(); // Прячем .aa
    $('.bb').show(); // Показываем .bb
  } else if($(this).hasClass('bb')) {
  // Если .bb
    $(this).hide(); // Прячем .bb
    $('.aa').show(); // Показываем .aa
  }
});
```

```css
.aa, .bb {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.aa {
  background: red;
}

.bb {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="aa">a</div>
<div class="bb" style="display: none;">b</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем так. У меня есть много контейнеров с разным контентом, они привязаны к списку селект. Когда я что то выбираю в селекте, показывается соответсвующий контейнер с содержимым, 18 фото, в каждом контейнере есть кнопка View More, по нажатию на которую появляется укрытый контейнер с дополнительными фото в данном контейнере.Мой код на эту кнопку работает, но только один раз в одном контейнере. Если же я после того как на неё нажал в контейнере 1,выбираю в селект контейнер 4 и он загружается, то кнопка view more уже не работает.Прошу совета, как сделатьчтобы могла во всех контейнерах работать